# Converter dynamic para query string

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão, querystring, dynamic

Há alguma maneira mais "elegante" de converter um `dynamic` para uma *query string*?

Atualmente estou fazendo com vários `Replace()` mas não é bem o que eu queria.

```
string data = new
{
    email = email,
    password = password
}
.ToString()
.Replace(',', '&')
.Replace(' ', char.MinValue)
.Replace('{', char.MinValue)
.Replace('}', char.MinValue);
```

Tentei criar uma extensão que para mim resolveria este caso, mas não funciona com o tipo `dynamic`

```
public static StringContent ToQueryString(this object model)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> query = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    dynamic data = model as dynamic;

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in data.GetType().GetProperties())
        query.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(data, null));

    return new StringContent(string.Join("&", query));
}
```

Comment: Eu não entendi direito seu código, mas, pelo visto se quer pegar uma objeto de qualquer tipo e transformar em query String seria isso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, você deveria usar o que tem pronto para codificar a URL ([.NET Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Web_HttpUtility_UrlEncode_System_String_) e [.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers?view=aspnetcore-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)).

Não deveria criar um método de extensão em `object`, ficará disponível para tudo e acho que você não tem ideia o quanto isto vai te trazer problemas.

Alias, quando usa `object` provavelmente está fazendo algo errado. Ele é útil em casos muito específicos que raros problemas precisam e mesmo assim provavelmente por limitação da plataforma.

Se `dynamic` não está funcionando tire ele, afinal ele não tem utilidade alguma aí. Quase sempre não tem.

Ou seja, este código está cheio de abusos de recursos desnecessários.

Certamente tem outras formas de alcançar o objetivo de forma melhor, e não falo de ser só mais elegante, é ser mais robusto, mais correto.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() => WriteLine(ToQueryString(new { nome = "Nome", valor = 10 }));

    public static string ToQueryString<T>(T model) {
        var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            query.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(model, null).ToString());
        return string.Join("&", query);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CoZqTa). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pY1vgZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/GetPropertiesAnyObject.cs).